# Inner Join With MAX function - SQLSERVER-

Tags: sql-server-2008, max, inner-join

I've looked for a solution to my problem, however believe I'm doing something wrong.

I need to select a row in a table, and this row has a column called 'SEQ' with a value from 0 to 200 (10-10). In the result, the line with the maximum SEQ field, but less than the first selected.

example:

```
+----------------------------+
| cod   cod_os   task    seq |
+----------------------------+
| 1     9000     wash    10  |
| 2     9000     dry     20  |
| 3     9000     polish  40  |
| 4     9003     ****    10  |
| 5     9000     park    80  |
| 6     9003     ****    20  |
| 7     9020     ****    10  |
| 8     9007     ****    10  |
| 9     9010     ****    10  |
| 10    9009     ****    10  |
| 11    9003     ****    30  |
| 12    9001     ****    10  |
| 13    9002     ****    10  |
| 14    9003     ****    40  |
| 15    9001     ****    20  |
+----------------------------+
```

expected result:

Obs: When the task is less of their ' OS ' the result should be the task itself . Ex: the earlier the 'wash' is 'wach'.

```
+------------------------------------+
| cod   cod_os   task    seq    prev |
+------------------------------------+
| 1     9000     wash    10       1  |
| 2     9000     dry     20       1  |
| 3     9000     polish  40       2  |
| 4     9003     ****    10       4  |
| 5     9000     park    80       3  |
| 6     9003     ****    20       4  |
| 7     9020     ****    10       7  |
| 8     9007     ****    10       8  |
| 9     9010     ****    10       9  |
| 10    9009     ****    10       10 |
| 11    9003     ****    30       6  |
| 12    9001     ****    10       12 |
| 13    9002     ****    10       13 |
| 14    9003     ****    40       11 |
| 15    9001     ****    20       12 |
+------------------------------------+
```

Take my code (SQL SERVER 2008):

```
    select
CAST(T0.COD_OS AS VARCHAR) +'/'+ RIGHT(('000' + CAST(T0.COD_OS_AUX AS VARCHAR)),3) 'OS_COMPLETO',
    T1.TIPO 'TIPOSERVICO',
    T2.NOME 'MAQUINA',
    T3.SUBTITULO 'SUB',
    T4.CLIENTE 'CLIENTE',
    T3.QTDE_PECAS 'QTD',
    t0.CODIGO 'COD',
    t0.SEQ 'SEQ',
    t0.OBS 'OBS',
    t0.DT_INCIO_PREVISTO 'INICIO',
    t0.DT_TERMINO_PREVISTO 'FIM',
    t0.TOTAL_HRS_TIME 'TOTAL',
    T4.CANCELADO,
    T4.CONCLUIDO,
    T5.SEQ 'ANTERIOR',
    (CASE WHEN T1.TIPO <> T6.TIPO THEN T6.TIPO ELSE 'REQ. MATERIAIS' END) 'ANTERIOR'

from [ProjectOne].[dbo].[TPRO_PRO] T0
    INNER JOIN [ProjectOne].[dbo].[TTP_MAQU] T1 ON T0.COD_TP_SERVICO=T1.CODIGO
    INNER JOIN [ProjectOne].[dbo].[TMAQUINA] T2 ON T0.COD_MAQUINA=T2.CODIGO
    INNER JOIN [ProjectOne].[dbo].[TOS_AUX] T3 ON T0.COD_OS=T3.COD_OS AND T0.COD_OS_AUX=T3.CODIGO
    INNER JOIN [ProjectOne].[dbo].[TPRO_PRO] T5 ON T5.COD_OS = T0.COD_OS AND T5.COD_OS_AUX = T0.COD_OS_AUX AND T0.SEQ > t5.SEQ
    INNER JOIN [ProjectOne].[dbo].[TTP_MAQU] T6 ON T5.COD_TP_SERVICO=T6.CODIGO     
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT T0.CODIGO,T0.CANCELADO,T0.CONCLUIDO, T1.NOME AS CLIENTE
        FROM [ProjectOne].[dbo].[TOS] T0 INNER JOIN [ProjectOne].[dbo].[TCLIENTE] T1 ON T0.COD_CLIENTE=T1.CODIGO
    ) T4 ON T4.CODIGO=T0.COD_OS AND T4.CANCELADO=0 AND T4.CONCLUIDO=0 and T0.FINALIZADO=0 and T3.COD_STAUS not in (3,4)
WHERE T0.DT_INCIO_PREVISTO <> '' 
ORDER BY T1.TIPO, t0.DT_TERMINO_PREVISTO, t0.COD_OS, T0.COD_OS_AUX
```

Comment: You ask for the line to include the maximum value of SEQ but also less than what you get from the first query. That seems like a contradiction since it can't fulfill both those conditions. Do you mean that it should return the line with the SEQ value that is the largest of the values that is less than the first SEQ? Also, how do you want it to react in situations where it could return several tuples from the second query?

Comment: I have a sequence of 'jobs' , which are organized by this ' SEQ ' field when I select a 'job' , I know the previous 'job' . The problem is that not always the previous job at 50 is 40 for example, it may be 30 or 20, if one has been deleted .

Comment: When the 'job' is the first and therefore have the lowest ' SEQ ' would like to return this same task duplicate , or none.

Comment: What I mean is that in your example Leandro and Julio both have the SEQ 20, as well as Jonas and Maria. If they are supposed to be the return of the second query, how should the result be treated since there are two or more possible values returned.

Comment: With the code above , my result is being several duplicate 'jobs' , showing all previous  'jobs'  to it. For example when I have the  'jobs'  40 , he is showing me to 40 with 30 being the last, to 40 with 20 being the front and 40 with 10 being the previous

Comment: Will not duplicate, as the code of the OS and OS_AUX are different. For each OS + OS_AUX , there is only ' SEQ ' distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that's what you're looking for, 
But given the table in youre example,
If you join it with itself on the same code_os and add the condition on the SEQ value (so it would be lower then the selected row), wouldn't selecting the top top row give you what you need?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestSEQ](
    [cod] [int] NULL,
    [cod_os] [int] NULL,
    [task] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [seq] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestSEQ]
           ([cod]
           ,[cod_os]
           ,[task]
           ,[seq])
     VALUES
           (1,9000,'wash',10),
           (2,9000,'dry',20),
           (3,9000,'polish',40),
           (4,9003,'****',10),
           (5,9000,'park',80),
           (6,9003,'****',20),
           (7,9020,'****',10),
           (8,9007,'****',10),
           (9,9010,'****',10),
           (10,9009,'****',10),
           (11,9003,'****',30),
           (12,9001,'****',10),
           (13,9002,'****',10),
           (14,9003,'****',40),
           (15,9001,'****',20)           
GO

declare @task varchar(50) = 'park'

SELECT  top 1 b.*
FROM    [TestSEQ] a 
    inner join [TestSEQ] b 
        on a.cod_os = b.cod_os
where 1=1
and a.cod_os = 9000
and a.task = @task
and b.seq < a.seq
order by b.seq desc
```

for all rows:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    
(
    SELECT  a.* , max(b.seq) NextSEQAfterMax
    FROM    [TestSEQ] a 
        inner join [TestSEQ] b 
            on a.cod_os = b.cod_os
    where 1=1
    and b.seq < a.seq
    group by a.cod , a.cod_os , a.task , a.seq
) a
    inner join TestSEQ b
        on a.cod_os = b.cod_os
        and a.NextSEQAfterMax = b.seq
```

Comment: Your code can be the beginning of the solution of my problem . But his problem is that I do not select only one line , I have to select all that are in a certain status , and their previous tasks. Using your code , I got only one result row .

Comment: Check the way you adjusted your code, there's no 50 in your sample so I can't verify your comment, but notice the join statement joins rows only if the seq is lower in the second table, to rule out situations of equality.
Good luck, hope you'll get it working.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem using your solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to help, mark the answer please if it assisted you, good day buddy.